# Is there a more terse/elegant way to format the following Social Security Number like String with or without Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

BEFORE:

```
EUTQQGOPED
```

AFTER:

```
EUT-QQG-OPED
```

The example below is what I came up with to add '-' to a 10 character String as part of a readability requirement.  The formatting pattern is similar to how a U.S Social Security Number is often formatted.

Is there a simpler, less verbose way of accomplishing the additional format?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String pin = "EUTQQGOPED";
        StringBuilder formattedPIN = new StringBuilder(pin);
        formattedPIN = formattedPIN.insert(3, '-').insert(7, '-');
        //output is EUT-QQG-OPED
        println formattedPIN
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you've done is the best way to do it, however you could make it more elegant by simply in-lining everything, as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    println new StringBuilder("EUTQQGOPED").insert(6, '-').insert(3, '-');
}
```

This kind of in-lining is possible due to StringBuilder providing a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (which allows method chaining).

Also note the transposition of the inserts, because the order you had them in means the first insert affects the parameters of the second insert. By ordering them largest-first means they are basically independent of each other.

And there's always... *"less code == good"* (as long as it's still readable, and in this case it is IMHO *more* readable)

Comment: Less code usually == bad as decreased readability and increased maintenance costs :)

Comment: More readable code == good (doesn't matter if less or more). :)

Comment: +1 Inlining the original code made all the difference in this case, this reads well.

Answer (score 5):

Could use regex, it's slightly clearer what you're doing, but prob not as efficient.

```
String formattedPin = pin.replaceAll("(.{3})(.{3})(.{4})", "$1-$2-$3")
System.out.println(formattedPin);
```

Comment: Creative use of regex. I like it.

Comment: Nice answer! Maybe I'd consider using `/(...)(...)(.*)/` as the regex, just to keep it extremely simple.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, I'd go with:

```
def pin = "EUTQQGOPED"
def formatted = [pin[0..2], pin[3..5], pin[6..-1]].join('-')
```

For brevity, this might be a hack, but it's very short (and I think it's quite readable too hehe):

```
def formatted = "-$pin"[1..3, 0, 4..6, 0, 7..10]
```

Comment: That second option is definitely succinct. It could also be used like this `def formatted = pin[0..2, "-", 3..5, "-", 6..9]`. Which makes it slightly more obvious what is going on (IMO).

Comment: @David I can't get that expression to work (throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException; I'm on Groovy 1.8.6). Are you sure it is valid Groovy? It would indeed make the intent clearer.

Comment: Ah, yeah you're right. Sorry, was mixing up between building a list (like you do in the first example) and slicing the String with indexes.

Answer (score 2):

These are a couple of options that Groovy gives you. They don't necessarily read very easily in this case, but they are nice and short.

```
    def pin = "EUTQQGOPED"

    // Option 1
    def formatted1 = "${pin[0..2]}-${pin[3..5]}-${pin[6..-1]}" 
    println formatted1

    // Option 2
    def pt1 = pin[0..2]
    def pt2 = pin[3..5]
    def pt3 = pin[6..-1]

    def formatted2 = pt1 << "-" << pt2 << "-" << pt3
    println formatted2
```

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I like the [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) option, I think breaking it up looks uglier.

```
    String pin = "EUTQQGOPED";
    System.out.println(String.format("%s-%s-%s", pin.substring(0, 3), pin.substring(3,6), pin.substring(6)));
```

Comment: I played with this as well.  I find the syntax intimidating.